# Wha't the best place to grab historical sophisticated data about stocks?

Tags: programming, historical-data, fundamentals

I am looking for an API which allow me to grab a data about companies & their stocks in the historical perspective. Like not only prices, but let's say balance sheets & cashflow statements each quarter, information about its bonds, credit ratings, etc.

I find few paid places in internet like eodhistoricaldata, but not sure they're the best, maybe I am missing some good place.

Comment: Tiingo.com has it for free for US stocks and I believe some others.  If you have an account, Interactive Brokers has this data as well

Comment: @amdopt thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlphaVantage: Privides 20 years of stock quote data

Data Feed Sources:

- https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/fundamentals.html
- https://blog.quandl.com/api-for-stock-data
- https://iextrading.com/
- https://iexcloud.io
- https://www.alphavantage.co/
- https://www.cloudquote.io/support/documentation/json_quote_api.php
- http://www.usfundamentals.com/

Answer (score 0):

The best (completely) free eod stocks data source I have found so far is [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) for Python.